# Running 'su - user sh -c "~/.profile"' returns "No such file" error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, .bash-profile

I have a shell script running as root with the following command:

```
ssh remotehost 'su - user sh -c "source /home/user/.profile; <command>"'
```

I get the following output:

```
bash: su - user sh -c "source /home/user/.profile; <command>": No such file or directory.
```

/home/user/.profile definitely exists on remotehost though. What's going on? Is there some other way to import the path that's defined in .profile?

Comment: This is the kind of command that requires very careful and exact quoting. Can you please create a command you're comfortable sharing exactly as is, and then run and post that command (instead of running the command you want, and then censoring it and its output before posting)?

Comment: It's treating the entire string as the name of a command, not a command followed by arguments.

Comment: Try debugging with `-v`.

Comment: Latter you will discover that you can only run `su` from a tty. Therefore you will need the `-tt` option of `ssh`.

Comment: Are you sure that what is in the question is what you tried? : I can not reproduce error: I have to add extra quotes to get this error.

Comment: According to su syntax the sh is out of place and should be in the argument of -c but really should not be required.  The command I would try is ssh remotehost 'su - user -c ". /home/user/.profile; <command>"' or perhaps ssh remotehost "su - user -c \". /home/user/.profile; <command>\"".